# Матрица гомографии для фотографии улиц

Tags: opencv

У меня есть две фотографии с google street view
У фотографии есть 4 параметра: широта и долгота (с которых сделана фотография), горизонтальный и вертикальный угол камеры. Так же есть широта и долгота объекта, который изображен на двух фотографиях.

Нужно посчитать матрицу гомографии между фотографиями.

Стандартные методы требуют знания сопоставимых точек, но этой информацией я в принципе не могу владеть. Знаю, что посчитать можно через матрицы ротации и калибровки, но не могу обобщить на случай 4-хмерного пространства (мой случай).

Как посчитать матрицу гомографии между этими двумя фотографиями?